# my controller doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i create an app , a login page and a controller like this :----->

--->here here :)

```js
(function(){
    'use strict';
    angular
        .module("loginApp",[])
        .controller("loginCtrl",loginCtrl);
    loginCtrl.$inject = ['$location','$scope','loginService'];
    function loginCtrl($location,$scope,loginService){
        var vm = $scope;
        vm.login = login;
        function login(){
            var user = vm.user;
            console.log(user);

        };
    }
})();
```

```html
<body ng-app="loginApp" ng-controller="loginCtrl">

<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <h2>Login</h2>
    <form name="form" ng-submit="login()" role="form" method="post">
        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': form.username.$dirty && form.username.$error.required }">
            <label for="username">Username</label>
            <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="form-control" ng-model="user.username" required />
            <span ng-show="form.username.$dirty && form.username.$error.required" class="help-block">Username is required</span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': form.password.$dirty && form.password.$error.required }">
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control" ng-model="user.password" required />
            <span ng-show="form.password.$dirty && form.password.$error.required" class="help-block">Password is required</span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-actions">
            <button type="submit" ng-disabled="form.$invalid || dataLoading" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
            <img ng-if="dataLoading"/>
            <a href="#/register" class="btn btn-link">Register</a>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

  ...................

<!-- App -->
<script src="angular/scripts/login.router.js"></script>
<script src="angular/scripts/controllers/login/loginCtrl.js"></script>
```

but when i click the button "login()" , nothing happend. i don't know why .

Comment: You forgot to include `angular.js`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you don't use the scope directly in your controller (good way) you have to set an alias in your html (loginCtrl as login). Afterwards you set the models and call ctrl-functions with the alias as prefix (login.user.username).

```html
<body ng-app="loginApp" ng-controller="loginCtrl as login">

<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <h2>Login</h2>
    <form name="form" ng-submit="login.login()" role="form" method="post">
        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': form.username.$dirty && form.username.$error.required }">
            <label for="username">Username</label>
            <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="form-control" ng-model="login.user.username" required />
            <span ng-show="form.username.$dirty && form.username.$error.required" class="help-block">Username is required</span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': form.password.$dirty && form.password.$error.required }">
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control" ng-model="login.user.password" required />
            <span ng-show="form.password.$dirty && form.password.$error.required" class="help-block">Password is required</span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-actions">
            <button type="submit" ng-disabled="form.$invalid || dataLoading" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
            <img ng-if="dataLoading"/>
            <a href="#/register" class="btn btn-link">Register</a>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

  ...................

<!-- App -->
<script src="angular/scripts/login.router.js"></script>
<script src="angular/scripts/controllers/login/loginCtrl.js"></script>
```